# Angular 4 With High Chart

Tags: angular, highcharts, highcharts-ng

Am trying with Angular 4 and Highcharts.
[Angular npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-highcharts), used this link to install angular cli on my machine. Imported module and added like exactly on the link. While compiling my code, am getting the following error. Does it ring to anyone?
[image: Error]

Comment: have you checked your node_modules if the file exist?

Comment: No the file is not exist on node_modules. I've installed the highchart through npm.

Comment: than install it in node_modules using npm.

Comment: You've used `highcharts` tag, unfortunately, your problem seems to be related only with npm.